# Expand shorthand increasing integer sequences

Tags: code-golf

Given an input of a list of numbers in the format of a shorthand increasing
integer sequence, output the sequence in full.

Shorthand increasing integer sequence format works by finding every number *n*
with fewer digits than the number preceding it, *m*. With *d* as the number of
digits in *n*, the last *d* digits of *m* are replaced with all the digits of
*n*. Here's an example input:

```
123 45 6 7 89 200
```

Applying the replacement rule, we first turn 45 into 145 because 45 < 123:

```
123 145 6 7 89 200
```

Repeatedly applying the same rule, this becomes:

```
123 145 146 7 89 200
123 145 146 147 89 200
123 145 146 147 189 200
```

The sequence is now sorted (there are no numbers for which the rule applies),
so this is the final output.

You may assume that

- shorthand notation is always used when possible. For example, input will be
  `12 3`, never `12 13`.
- numbers will never decrease while remaining the same number of digits. For
  example, input will never be `333 222`.
- applying the shorthand rule will never result in a number that is still less
  than the previous number in the sequence. For example, input will never be
  `123 12`.
- numbers will always be positive integers and never contain leading 0s (if
  using a string format).
- the full, expanded sequence will never contain duplicate numbers. (However,
  the shorthand sequence might; ex. `10 1 20 1` -> `10 11 20 21`.)
- there will be at least one number in the input.

Input and output can be either lists/arrays of numbers/strings or a single
string with elements separated by any non-digit.

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes will win.

Test cases, with input and output on alternating lines:

```
1 2 3 10 1 2 20 5 100 200 10 3 5 26 9 99 999 9999
1 2 3 10 11 12 20 25 100 200 210 213 215 226 229 299 999 9999
223 1184 334 441 5 927 2073 589 3022 82 390 5 9
223 1184 1334 1441 1445 1927 2073 2589 3022 3082 3390 3395 3399
5 10 5 20 5 30 5 40 5 50 5
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55
7 8 9 70 80 90 700 800 900 7000 8000 9000
7 8 9 70 80 90 700 800 900 7000 8000 9000
42
42
```

Comment: Challenge is pretty old, but a) can the input be empty? b) can the input contain only one number?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'll go ahead and say there will be ≥1 numbers in the input.

Answer (score 7):

## Jelly, 7 bytes

```
DUṛ"\UḌ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RFXhuZsiXFXhuIw&input=&args=MTIzLDQ1LDYsNyw4OSwyMDA) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RFXhuZsiXFXhuIwKxpPDh-KCrOG5hOKCrOG5m-KBtg&input=WzEsMiwzLDEwLDEsMiwyMCw1LDEwMCwyMDAsMTAsMyw1LDI2LDksOTksOTk5LDk5OTldLFsyMjMsMTE4NCwzMzQsNDQxLDUsOTI3LDIwNzMsNTg5LDMwMjIsODIsMzkwLDUsOV0sWzUsMTAsNSwyMCw1LDMwLDUsNDAsNSw1MCw1XSxbNyw4LDksNzAsODAsOTAsNzAwLDgwMCw5MDAsNzAwMCw4MDAwLDkwMDBd).

#### How it works

```
DUṛ"\UḌ  Main link. Input: A (list of integers)

D        Convert each integer to a list of its base 10 digits.
 U       Reverse each digit list.
    \    Do a cumulative reduce, applying the dyadic link to the left:
   "       For each pair of corresponding digits:
  ṛ          Select the right one.
           Vectorization leaves digits that do not have a counterpart untouched.
     U   Reverse the resulting digit arrays.
      Ḍ  Convert from base 10 to integer.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, <s>45</s> 42 bytes

3 bytes off thanks [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

```
a=>a.map(x=>z=z.slice(0,-x.length)+x,z='')
```

The above function expects an array of strings.

```js
f=
a=>a.map(x=>z=z.slice(0,-x.length)+x,z='')

F=a=>document.body.innerHTML+='<pre>'+a+'\n'+f(a)+'\n</pre>';

F(['1','2','3','10','1','2','20','5','100','200','10','3','5','26','9','99','999','9999'])
F(['223','1184','334','441','5','927','2073','589','3022','82','390','5','9'])
F(['5','10','5','20','5','30','5','40','5','50','5'])
F(['7','8','9','70','80','90','700','800','900','7000','8000','9000'])
```

Comment: Save 4 bytes using `z=z.slice(0,-x.length)+x,z=''` (or variable name of your choice).

Comment: @Neil. Nice one! I knew there should have a way to do that

Comment: (Sorry for miscounting the saving.) Also, the string version is unnecessary as it turns out that `s=>s.split\` \`.map(` is 2 bytes (I double-checked this time) shorter than `s=>s.replace(/\d+/g,`.

Comment: @Neil. Valid point. I just leaved it there because was my first goal when answering... but you are right

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 45 bytes

```
+`(?=(?<1>\d)+)(?<=(\d)(?(1)x)(?<-1>\d)+ )
$1
```

Uses balancing groups to count the digits which costs a lot. Haven't found a better approach yet but I'm interested in it.

[Try it online here.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2AoPz0oPzwxPlxkKSspKD88PShcZCopKD8oMSkoPyEpKSg_PC0xPlxkKSsgKQokMQ&input=MTIzIDE0NSAxNDYgNyA4OSAyMDAgNTQzMjEw)

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 35 characters

```
<D>=@set{p;@fill-right{${p;};$0}}$p
```

Input: string with numbers separated by anything, output string.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<D>=@set{p;@fill-right{${p;};$0}}$p' <<< '123 45 6 7 89 200'
123 145 146 147 189 200
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 39 characters

```ruby
->a{l='';a.map{|c|l=l[0..-c.size-1]+c}}
```

Input: array of strings, output: array of strings.

Sample run:

```
2.1.5 :001 > ->a{l='';a.map{|c|l=l[0..-c.size-1]+c}}[%w{123 45 6 7 89 200}]
 => ["123", "145", "146", "147", "189", "200"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
s=''
for i in input():s=s[:max(len(s)-len(i),0)]+i;print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWXZ0rLb9IIVMhMw@ICkpLNDStim2Lo61yEys0clLzNIo1dUFUpqaOgWasdqZ1QVFmXolC8f//0eqG6joK6kYgwhhEGBqASbigEZhvCpEygIgYIBQaw2WNzECkJZiAkjDKUj0WAA)